# Suppose that a<0, how do you go about proving the density property of the Real Numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, elementary-number-theory

So the whole statement was:

*Prove that for any real number* $a\lt0$, *there exists a real number* $b$ *such that* $a\lt b\lt0$.

I understand the basics of the density property, however, all the examples that use this property included this statement: "*suppose that* $a\gt 0$." So I am very lost as to what to do to prove this as for this to be true, $a$ would have to be positive. However, for what I'm trying to prove, $a$ and $b$ would have to be negative, correct? Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

For those that answer my question, thank you in advance.

Comment: Check out the axioms of [ordered fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field)

Comment: Are you sure the question was not "Prove that for any real number a<0 there exists a rational number b such that a<b<0"?

Comment: @P.Lawrence I'm sure that it said "there exists a real number b", it's written on my assignment paper. Thank you for clarifying with me though, I was very confused when I first saw the question too.

Answer (score 2):

You can take $b = \frac{a}{2}$.